# ShowModalDialog from Sharepoint hosted app not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, project-server

I'm having the same issue like in multiple other discussions:

**Chrome**:
`Cannot read property 'defaultDialogWidth' of undefined`

**Firefox**: `SP.Res is undefined`

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/76044
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/bf1dc5ea-c045-48f6-b0cd-144d0ab7c1ce/spreshiddenbuttonvaluebeforedialog-is-null-or-not-an-object?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious
http://chuvash.eu/2012/02/13/scriptresx-ashx-in-sharepoint/

I have tried various solutions posted online but none seem to work. Can anyone tell me which dependencies I'm missing? (I'm not using a masterpage)

I have the following code:

```
    function showTimeSheetLinesDialog(guid) {
        var options = {};
        options.width = 500;
        options.height = 640;
        //options.url = getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl') + '/Pages/TimeSheetLineDetail.aspx?guid=' + guid + '&json=' + $("#" + guid).attr('data-lines');
        options.title = 'Dialog title';
        options.allowMaximize = false;
        options.showClose = true;

        //SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options), "SP.js")
        //SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);


        // parent.SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);

}
```

And the following scripts loaded:

```
 <head>
    <base target="_parent" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ps.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?culture=nb-no&name=SP.Res"></script>


    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Warning.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: If you try your code on-premise (or just not from a "Hosted App"), does it work then ?

Comment: I got it half to work by adding all the script files that were missing manually, I am still missing the style and stuff. However, I was wondering if it is possible to open a dialog on the page from the web part. If it's not I don't even have to bother to try and get it to work.

Comment: When you say script files, do you mean custom script files or the ones that should be there generated by SP ? I do believe it's possible to open a dialog from a webpart. In the end it's just a Javascript call (which makes me believe that it should be possible from App Hosted too).

Comment: Yes, adding ScriptResx.ashx?culture=en%2Dus&name=SP%2ERes and sp.core.js got me something that looks like a modal dialog (it loads the other page) but without any style (can't move it, isn't appearing on top of the page like it should, ..) and it appears inside the webpart only. I'm starting to wonder if I did the right thing by not using any masterpage for my webpart?

Comment: You should not have to use a master page for your webpart, put any style files into the style libary and deploy them together with the webpart. Have you registered the necessary JS through your webpart (not the ScriptResx) ? Check this post for details: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/146f3efa-e1ab-4625-b359-1ee3e35507e6/content-editor-webpart-jquery-code-is-not-getting-loaded-first-time?forum=appsforsharepoint

Comment: My webpart works just fine otherwise (using JSOM and OData queries). It's just the dialog that doesn't work, that's why I'm not sure what I'm missing here..

Comment: Are you sure you don't need this in the App Hosted scenario ? SP.SOD.RegisterSod("SP.js", "\_layouts\SP.js");
SP.SOD.RegisterSod("SP.Core.js", "\_layouts\SP.Core.js");
SP.SOD.RegisterSod("SP.Runtime.js", "\_layouts\SP.Runtime.js");

Comment: Adding those lines changes nothing (when you change them to registerSod, since RegisterSod is undefined), my old functionality still works and the dialog doesn't. I've included a screenshot of what the dialog now looks like: http://imgur.com/1yiCikC (this is when I open the webpart directly, and appears below the normal content).

Comment: Try calling the SP.js from the front end page (ascx), and then use in backend the foll line:- SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options)

Comment: It's a sharepoint hosted app, no ascx files. Just javascript and aspx files I'm afraid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I eventually found the missing dependencies myself, incase anyone ever runs into the same problem, they are the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?culture=en%2Dus&name=SP%2ERes"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';

    // Set the style of the client web part page to be consistent with the host web.
    (function () {
        var hostUrl = '';
        if (document.URL.indexOf('?') != -1) {
            var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                var p = decodeURIComponent(params[i]);
                if (/^SPHostUrl=/i.test(p)) {
                    hostUrl = p.split('=')[1];
                    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + hostUrl + '/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx" />');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (hostUrl == '') {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/themable/corev15.css" />');
        }
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this link ?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c3666ce1-e326-4dc2-aa58-20ade46b2cce/open-a-page-in-modal-dialog-from-sharepoint-hosted-app-or-auto-hosted-app?forum=appsforsharepoint

It mentions this:

> The web page that hosts your app must have the following:
>
> `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming1" runat="server" />`

Comment: Although I didn't include this in my original post, I do have this in my web page.

Comment: I think the answer in this link is not correct, or is missing some key information. AllowFraming in the host page has nothing to do with the app dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Add `_ribbon = new Object();` after `sp.ui.dialog.js` script loaded.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    _ribbon = new Object();

</script>
```