# Invoking SP.ModalDialog in Sharepoint 2013 Hosted Apps

Tags: client-object-model, sharepoint-hosted-app

I'm building a SharePoint 2013, SharePoint Hosted app project using the JSOM api. I have to make use of the  SP.UI.ModalDialog to popup some content in the app. 
I have used the getScript method to load the sp.js, sp.runtime.js and SP.RequestExecutor.js. I also have the necessary Microsoft SP js(MicrosoftAjax.js) and 
other jQuery files referenced in my app. Even after loading these files, when I call the method to show a simple popup on the screen I get a 
JavaScript error saying :

> Error: Unable to get property 'execute' of undefined or null
>   reference.

Following is the code i have used in the app.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    var scriptbase = HOST_WEB_URL + '/_layouts/15/';
    $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.Runtime.js',
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js',
                function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', openDialog); }
            );
        }
    );

});

function openDialog() {
    var options = {
        url: "/_layouts/15/accessdenied.aspx?IsDlg=1",
        title: 'Sharing  Information',
        width: 500,
        height: 200,
        allowMaximize: false,
        showClose: true
    };

    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);

    return false;

}
```

The error comes up with the SP.SOD.execute().

Has anyone faced this issue before? Can anyone help me correct this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to get it work ?
I don't know why microsoft make it so difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The web page that hosts your app must have the following:

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming1" runat="server" />
```

You can try the following code from a client app part:

```
function ShowSharingInformation() {

    var options = {
        url: "/_layouts/15/aclinv.aspx",
        tite: 'Sharing  Information',
        allowMaximize: false,
        showClose: true,
        width: 430,
        height: 230
    };

    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
    return false;

}
```

OR you can try:

[ShowModalDialog from Sharepoint hosted app not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92330/showmodaldialog-from-sharepoint-hosted-app-not-working)

Comment: I have <WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming1" runat="server" /> already in my app part page.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass in options as an array, pass them in as individual parameters.

While, according to [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407807%28v=office.14%29.aspx), it says to pass it as an object array, a comment at the bottom states that is fails when executed this way.

Comment: I think what is happening is that when you pass all the parameters in seperatly, it puts them into an object array in the function itself?  I don't know, just a guess.

Comment: You mean like so - SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', url,title,width,height,allowMaximize,showClose);

Comment: Yeah, or pass them by their values as well.  so it could be "/_layouts/15/accessdenied.aspx?IsDlg=1",'Sharing  Information', 500, and so on.

Comment: I tried it both ways but no change.

Comment: Are you sure you added it to the web code correctly?  The error is saying that one or more parts of the execute method is null, or undefined.  Which means it hasn't been created yet.  Make sure this script will wait for all value, including the scripts, to be loaded before the script executes.

Comment: I am using the getScript method to chain-load the scripts. At the end of the chain is the call to the openDialog(). It should ensure the scripts are loaded before execute() is called right?

Comment: I am not entirely sure on the exact execution of scripts, but I think they run asynchronously.  So, while the openDialog is called last, items may not be fully initialized by the time it reaches that step.  Like I said, I'm not 100% sure, but I do know you are getting that error because on of the parameters you are passing to the function has not been initialized yet.